# how to access custom classes in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a custom class with few method in it. e.g.

```
 class MyClass{

  method1 ();

  method2();
}
```

Now I want to create object of this class and use it inside a controller method

class DefaultController{

```
public function myAction()
{
  //here I want to able to create object of MyClass, is it possible? 
}
```

}

Q1. where should I store this class in symfony2 structuere e.g. inside src dir?

Q2. How can I use this class method inside the controller of a bundle?

Comment: The documentation about the [service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) could be interesting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your class in the src folder, it will be autoloaded, ie: you can simply do:

```
$foo = new \MyClass();
$foo->method1();
```

in your **Controller**.

A good approach would be to put your classes in the Bundle you are likely to use them:

```
src/YourCompany/YourBundle/MyClass.php
```

In this way however don't forget to put the namespace declaration on top of your MyClass file:

```
namespace YourCompany\YourBundle;
class MyClass{
   //..
}
```

You can put your classes on the base folder of your bundle, or use other nested folders to better differentiate a set of classes from each others, for eg:

```
src/YourCompany/YourBundle/Listener/MyClassListener.php
src/YourCompany/YourBundle/Manager/MyClassManager.php
```

For more info see the [Best practice on Bundles structure of Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html)